# How to create GlobalSign Timestamp Digest?

Tags: pdf, digital-signature

I am attempting to use the Global Sign Digital Signing Service API to sign a PDF document. I have received some of their documentation. But I am unable to understand their request to provide a "digest". The documentation suggests I make the digest with SHA256, HEX encode it, and put it in Upper Case letters. However, I am not sure what they want encoded. All it says is an "Object", but not what goes in the object.

**Documentation Page:**

https://downloads.globalsign.com/acton/media/2674/digital-signing-service-api-documentation#timestamp__digest__get

They have two References in their Signing API:

- **/identity/{id}/sign/{digest};** Sign a Hash:
  Once a private key and certificate are created and while valid within a single signing session, they can be used to perform multiple signing operations. The digest must be a Hex encoded SHA256 message digest in upper cases. The returned signature will also be Hex encoded.
- **/timestamp/{digest};** Request Timestamp: This API provides RFC3161 compliant timestamp to include in the signature.

I have credentials to work with GlobalSign. I was able to successfully use their "/login" api call. The next step was to use their "/timestamp/{digest}" api. What goes in the digest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to create your digest, you need to hash the pdf you would like signed. It's expected to be upper case. Here is how I did it.

```
$pdf = file_get_contents("chicken.pdf");
$digest = strtoupper(hash('sha256', $pdf));
```

Also, make sure your headers are correct. It should contain the bearer token received from the /login call like this:

```
$headers = array('Authorization: Bearer '. $access_token);
```

If you leave unnecessary info in the headers you'll get a 504 timeout.

Comment: An improvement to this accepted answer could be `hash_file()` instead of a combination of `file_get_contents()` and `hash()`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform most of the signing process locally – the only difference is that you call the API instead of using a local crt/pem/key file (or a smartcard).

If you are trying to create a signature which would be visible in apps like Adobe Reader (in their "Signatures" panel), you will need to do so according to these documents:

- Adobe [Portable document format — Part 1: PDF 1.7](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf#page=474) (starting at section 12.8, "Digital signatures")
- ETSI [Electronic Signatures and Infrastructures (ESI);
  CMS Advanced Electronic Signatures (CAdES)](https://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/101700_101799/101733/02.02.01_60/ts_101733v020201p.pdf)
- ETSI [Electronic Signatures and Infrastructures (ESI);
  PAdES Baseline Profile](https://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/103100_103199/103172/02.02.02_60/ts_103172v020202p.pdf)

The first document (the PDF specification) tells you exactly which byte ranges are included in the digest, as well as how the resulting signature is embedded back into the PDF document.

Note that PDF [requires](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/43898/is-it-possible-to-have-a-pades-signature-with-only-a-timestamp) timestamps to be paired with a digital signature – you cannot have *just* the timestamp.

Comment: A PDF can have a timestamp only signature in PDF 2.0 (ISO/DIS 32000-2 - 12.8.5.2 Initial document timestamp dictionary) or in PDF 1.7. through an extension level (see e.g PAdES LTV Profile). The question you're refering asks for a PAdES signature with only a timestamp.